# sed to rebuild a manifest from a 2nd file

Tags: shell, filter, sed, while-loop

I'd like to replace a file content for *some* lines (not all of them) matching another file content:

**File1** is a manifest with this format (thousands of lines):

```
...    
f 755 myself mygroup /opt/app/fileabc a991a508b1166fb14448f303bba7662287b7a827f3761f
f 555 myself mygroup /opt/app/filedef 3bba766209dcd21a0793190b287b7a8a508b1114448f30
...
```

The last part being sha256sum of the file referenced just ahead.
I recompute and recalculate sha256sum for some of these files, ending up in
**File2:**

```
...
645278b945d6b52c48a1851765c72a8eb1e7030c5ee /opt/app/fileabc
1765c72a8eb1e703aa3ac3ba01d2160c0c83df464ee /opt/app/filedef
...
```

with the same filename obviously, but a different sha256sum.
File1 is 1k lines big, while File2 has only 155 lines updates to present.

How can I make `file1` updated with the contents of `file2`?
This command ends up in 155k lines, with many times the same lines added, and not even with the expected replacements:

```
while read sha file; do
    sed "s;$file (\w+);$file $sha;" file1
done <file2
```

Comment: Please [edit] the example in your question to include some lines that should not change and show the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ sha[$2]=$1; next } $5 in sha{ $6=sha[$5] } 1' file2 file1
f 755 myself mygroup /opt/app/fileabc 645278b945d6b52c48a1851765c72a8eb1e7030c5ee
f 555 myself mygroup /opt/app/filedef 1765c72a8eb1e703aa3ac3ba01d2160c0c83df464ee
```

The above assumes there are no spaces in your file names or anywhere else except where shown in your example.

Comment: Thank you. I always think I HAVE to use sed while I'm no expert ;)

Comment: Ah, it looks like I have now both lines from file1 and file2 in the output, but the sha256 was not replaced :(
Comparing file size: file1 was 21169 lines and File2 113, your command returns 21282 lines ...

Comment: Then you didn't run the command I show in my answer or your input files don't look like the ones in your question. My best guess is you provided the input files in the wrong order when you ran the command - note that it's file2 and then file1, not the other way around.

Comment: Aha, of course I had a typo which was compatible with awk syntax, thus didn't return an error.

Perfect, and thank you.

I think I can analyze the syntax and reuse it, the fields 2, 1 and 6 and 5 used are explicit enough.